# Configuring JBoss Negotiation on UNIX machine

Tags: unix, jboss, active-directory, spnego

I'm trying to configure JBoss Negotiation on UNIX machine on Microsoft Active Directory using this link
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringJBossNegotiationInAnAllWindowsDomain?_sscc=t

```
ktpass -princ HTTP/10.222.105.36@DEG01.DEV -pass * -mapuser spnego@DEG01.DEV 
ktab -k c:/service.keytab -a HTTP/10.222.105.36@DEG01.DEV
```

but i get the error

```
Client not found in Kerberos database (6)
```

Can anyone confirm that my unix machine IP should be defined on the Active Directory?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a pre-requisite for Kerberos authentication to work is a correct DNS and reverse-DNS entries for hostnames and IP addresses.

The aim of this constraint is to involve an additional tier in the security team but the all-in-one ActiveDirectory breaks a little this idea.

To validate your setup, you can use Kerberos command line tools (MIT or Heimdal) on Unix:

- with a correct `/etc/krb5.conf` and default realm set
- `kinit user` does a password based authentication
- `kvno HTTP/yourIP` acquires a TGS for this SPN
- `kvno HTTP/yourhost.yourdomain.com` if you have registered alternate SPNs with `setspn -a`
- `klist -ef` to look at TGT and TGS tickets in cache with flags and encryption
- `kdestroy` to flush the user's cache
- `kinit -k -t service.keytab HTTP/yourIP` to test keytab based authentication